# Monotone Characteristic Function

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ be a continuous, symmetric random variable such that its characteristic function $\phi_X$ is real, symmetric and with $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi_X(t)=0$.
What other properties must $X$ have in order to guarantee that $\phi_X$ is monotone in the interval $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: I do not know conditions ensuring that $\phi_X$ is monotone on $[0,+\infty[$. To have $\phi_X$ monotone and convex on $[0,+\infty[$, you have to take mixtures of distributions with densities $x \mapsto (a/\pi)\mathrm{sinc}^2(ax)$. But characterising those densities is not simple.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Contrast the typography of these two lines: $$ \begin{align} & (a/\pi) \mathrm{sinc}^2(ax) \\ & (a/\pi) \operatorname{sinc}^2(ad) \end{align} $$ And also of these two: $$ \begin{align} & \mathrm{sinc}x \\ & \operatorname{sinc} x \end{align} $$ In the second example in each of those pairs $\operatorname{sinc}$ is coded as `\operatorname{sinc}` and in the first as `\mathrm{sinc}`. So you see that `\mathrm{sinc}` does not result in proper context-dependent horizontal spacing and `\operatorname{sinc}` does. That is what `\operatorname` is for.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Thank you for this explanation.